# Help in iframe auto size

Tags: php, iframe

.Need help guys, I have created a php page named picture.php. In this page I am retrieving a certain image from the database where I used the following codes to display the retrieved image:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

.next, I want to use this page to serve as the source for an image to be displayed in an iframe using the following code:

```
<a id="various3" href="picture.php" title="<?php echo $info; ?>"><img class="last" src="./images/page11.jpg" /></a>
```

.various 3 is a jquery class where when i click the  tag various 3 will pop-up an Iframe with picture.php inside it. and what i want to do is to set the size of the Iframe based on what is the size of the image from picture.php. help me with this please!

Answer (score 0):

Here is tutorial for you to start from--> [Here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-get-image-size/)

You will have to store the resulting values within an array, or two separate variables.

In you iframe, this should work:

```
<?php
    $valueWidth=500; 
    $valueHeight=250; 
?>

<iframe src="" width="<?= $valueWidth ?>" height="<?= $valueHeight ?>"
```

Comment: You should remove "px" from width/height. $valueWidth = 500; $valueHeight = 250; Otherwise you will get an error.